# Why is mmap failing with EINVAL when offset is non-negative (but is a multiple of sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE))?

Tags: c, driver, embedded-linux, mmap, petalinux

Firstly a bit of context about the machine I'm working on (it's a SOM with a SoC that includes a FPGA and two CPU, and on one of them there is a linux OS running).

Characteristics:

- Board : [Microzed](http://zedboard.org/product/microzed)
- SoC: [Zynq 7020](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug585-Zynq-7000-TRM.pdf)
- OS : Petalinux 2019.2
- Kernel version : 4.19.0-xilinx-v2019.2
- Processor type : ARMv7 Processor rev 0 v7l (armv7l)

I have a custom peripheral implemented on the FPGA that provides a standard AXI4 interface to a BRAM memory (thanks to [this component](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/axi_bram_ctrl/v4_0/pg078-axi-bram-ctrl.pdf)). This peripheral is registered in my device-tree and is accessible through the generic-uio driver of the kernel (more [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/uio-howto.html#how-uio-works) about this).

The size of the BRAM memory is 32kB. Here are the mapping characteristics that appear in `/sys/class/uio/uioX/maps/map0/` :

- addr   = 0x40000000
- offset = 0x0
- size   = 0x00008000

I'm working on a C code that simply aims to read this BRAM memory and log what is inside in a text file. In order to do so I use `mmap` (here is its [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)) to create some memory projections of the file located in `/dev/uioX` (that corresponds to my device).

I want to use only the file pages I need, more precisely mapping the file page per page. Here is the function I use to create the mapping of one page:

```
/**
 * @brief Get a pointer to the corresponding file page
 * 
 * @param filePage file page number
 * @param fd pointer where the file descriptor will be stored
 * @return int* 
 */
int *getFilePagePointer(int *fd, unsigned int filePage)
{
    // open driver file
    *fd = open("/dev/uio1", O_RDWR);
    if (*fd == -1)
    {
        int errsv = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening /dev/uio1 : errno %d (%s).\n", errsv, strerror(errsv));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // choose projection parameters
    int length = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    int offset = filePage * sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);

    // create mapping
    void *filePagePointer = mmap((void *)NULL, (size_t)length, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, *fd, (off_t)offset);
    if (filePagePointer == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        int errsv = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while mapping file page : errno %d (%s).\n", errsv, strerror(errsv));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return (int *)filePagePointer;
}
```

And then the issue: it works perfectly well if `filePage` (i.e. offset) is `0` but if it is strictly positive, it fails with `errno = 22`.

Unless I missed something in the man page, all parameters are valid (`offset` is a multiple of `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)`, `addr` is `NULL`, `length`is strictly positive and not too large, and flags are correct).
So, why an EINVAL ?...

Comment: Does it happen for *any* positive value of `filePage`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried 1, 2, 3, 4 and still errno 22...

Comment: What's more `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)` and `getconf PAGE_SIZE` are both `4096`.

Comment: The mmap flags argument needs to be `MAP_SHARED`, not `MAP_PRIVATE`.

Comment: It could be that nobody ever got around to implementing support for offset > 0 in the generic-uio driver. Does the mmap call succeed if you replace /dev/uio1 with a regular file that's big enough to cover the mapping you're trying to create?

Comment: @IanAbbott I tried this too, but it doesn't work. Why should it be `MAP_SHARED` ?

Comment: @zwol It works when using a regular file so I guess you're right ! Do you want to answer the question or can I do it myself ?

Comment: @tjustel Looks like ensc already covered it.

Comment: @tjustel `MAP_PRIVATE` certainly wouldn't work if you need to write to device memory because it maps virtual memory as "copy on write". I'm not sure if it can be used for read-only memory, but the convention is to use `MAP_SHARED` for mapping device memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[kernel driver](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/uio/uio.c?h=v4.19.134#n655) does

```
static int uio_find_mem_index(struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    struct uio_device *idev = vma->vm_private_data;

    if (vma->vm_pgoff < MAX_UIO_MAPS) {
        if (idev->info->mem[vma->vm_pgoff].size == 0)
            return -1;
        return (int)vma->vm_pgoff;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So it seems, `offset` is the map index (like in `map0`) but not the position within the memory.

You have to `mmap()` the whole memory.

Comment: What do you mean ? I read [here](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/memory_mapping.html) _vm_pgoff - the offset of the area within the file_ so isn't it what I want ?

Comment: @tjustel It's up to the driver implementing mmap how `vm_pgoff` is to be interpreted. UIO interprets it as an index to select which memory mapping to use, since a UIO device can have several memory mappings. See [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/uio-howto.html#mmap-device-memory).

Comment: All right can you provide the sources of this snippet, and a bit more information on this ?

Comment: @tjustel The snippet is from "drivers/uio/uio.c".

Comment: So this is a design bug in the driver? I don't understand how this is even plausibly *supposed* to work since on most archs the actual mmap (mmap2) syscall takes offset as a number of 4096-byte units, which gets multiplied by 4096 before it's passed to other layers in the kernel.